# Magento 2 - Using observer how to Set CMS block to category description block programmatically

Tags: event-observer, magento2.3.4, programmatically

Using observer how to **set catalog categories content Add CMS Block (category.description) programmatically**

My observer:

```
<?php
namespace Zero\DescBlock\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

/**
 * Class CollectionObserver
 * @package Vendor\Module\Observer
 */
class CollectionObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver
     */
    protected $layerResolver;

    /**
     * CollectionObserver constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
     */
    public function __construct(

        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
    ) {
        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $layer = $this->layerResolver->get();
        $activeFilters = $layer->getState()->getFilters();
        foreach ($activeFilters as $filter)
        {
           $filterLabel = $filter->getLabel();
           $filterValue = $filter->getValue();
        }
    }
}
```

**Condition :** Here my filterLabel is, **apple** and **orange** if filterLabel is apple i need to set cms block identifier my_apple if orange cms block identifier my_orange.

**I am added cms block to Product listing page category description section,.**

path :

app\design\frontend\Zero\mytheme\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_category_view.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="category.description">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">cms_block_identifier</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

How to merge into my observer?

Comment: if customer can add 2 filter at a time then ???

Comment: Take last attribute.

Comment: 1 more quation you create all block for filter ???

Comment: I created normal cms block, based on that attributes i need to set my cms block.

Comment: like my_red,my_orange,my_white etc ??

Comment: correct, you are right

Comment: Eg: If apple attributes selected i need to set my cms block my_red

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119115/discussion-between-zus-and-rk-rathod).